# VBA & Excel across different platforms

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

In my workplace we have several different types of systems.

Surface Pro's running Office 2016
Surface Pro's running Office 2013
Thin Clients running Office 2010
Desktops for Accessibility users running Office 2010

I develop VBA solutions that have to work across all of the above, and run into trouble with only one scenario.

I use a Surface Pro with Office 2016. If I build a document, I can run the macros I create on the Surface Pro's and Thin clients without issue, but the Desktop PC's running Office 2010 don't even get the option to turn on the macros.

If I open the file up on a desktop (seldom have access to one) and save it using that system, any other user on a desktop can open it up and the macros will work, but if anyone from one of the other systems opens it up and saves it, the desktop users will go back to square one.

At first I thought this would have been a compatibility issue relating to architecture

Can anyone think of anything before I pull the remainder of my hair out? I really want to be able to solve issues for the people having problems on desktops without having to find one myself, or worse - give them any passwords

Cheers

Comment: If you have multiple users on different platforms in a work environment then it should be safe to assume you're intimately aware of office's macro security and therefore are not having certificates revoked from a project because it was saved by a non-key holding user. it should be safe to assume that. should.  just like how one should be able to assume the power switch is on, the device is plugged in, the user is sitting at the appropriate terminal, and all utilities have been paid..... so yeah, I'd be remiss to not mention macro security settings or certificates getting cancelled by users

Comment: just to add, the odds of it being a certificate issue may increase greatly if your customers have a tool they made with the macro recorder but aren't proficient with the editor and are not vba literate.  i have coached  users to create personal certificates so they could sign a project if they monkeyed in the wrong module.  may not be the best idea but it saves my time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VBA Tools and uncheck all objects marked as missing under References.

Comment: Nothing is marked as missing, that occurs from time to time where the object libraries are an issue - but they are predicated by runtime errors, whereas in these scenarios there are no errors, the macros simply don't function as if the VBA were disabled - its rather odd :)